# How to get the most recent directories by date in Linux?

Tags: linux, date, terminal

I have a set of directories with names such as `4`, `_4_201703140220`, `_4_201703150220`. Where the first number is the directory ID, and the trailing numbers are ISO-standard date strings. These are used by Jenkins, but that's probably not relevant here.

Here's a sample listing:

```
_41_20170322145757/
_41_20170323110416/
_41_20170323110720/
_42_20170322095600/
_42_20170322103112/
_42_20170324120233/
```

Every directory contains revisions of the same data, but I wish to know the latest for each ID. In the above case this would be `_41_20170323110720/` and `_42_20170324120233/`.

Is there a simple command I can use to get a list of the latest directories for each ID? Or a python file will work as well.

Comment: You neglected to mention, so in case it isn't obvious to anyone here the numbers appended at the end are date strings, and poster wants only the directory corresponding to the most recent date.  Is this a correct summation?  Also, can we assume this is a Unix terminal?

Comment: OOps sorry.. But you got it.. On it for edit

Comment: Otherwise, assuming the directories' timestamps are also written date order, this will do what you want https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/136976/get-the-latest-directory-not-the-latest-file `ls -td -- * | head -n 1` This sorts the directories by timestamp (not filename) then gets the first in the list.

Comment: Is there any possibility that the directories can be copied or updated in a manner that breaks the correlation between the *date string* contained in the directory name and the actual date/time?

Answer (score 0):

I found myself creating a monster, but assuming you only want the file with the most recent date at the end of it in that form, this Python expression should do what you want:

```
python -c "import os; print max(((x, x.split('_')[-1]) for x in os.listdir('.')), key=lambda x: x[1])[0]"
```

**Explanation**

`os.listdirs('.')` Get all the directories in the current path

`(x for x in y)` create a generator expression

`.split('_')[-1]` split each directory name on `_` and only take the last portion

`max(<whatever>, key=value)` find the maximum based upon a special key
This allows us to use a function to tell if "red" is larger than "blue"

`lambda x: x[1]` create an inlinefunction (called a lambda) which returns only part of an iterable (a list we can hunt through)
For a list containing `[1, 'r', 3, 'z', 'b']`, it will return the element in position 1, `'r'`

We use this to find the "maximum" date, which is conveniently the most recent under your scheme (201703150220 is larger than 201603150220).

`max()` then returns a tuple containing the full filename and the date we tried to match
`"_4_201703150220"` becomes `("_4_201703150220", "201703150220")`

Then taking the `[0]` index get the first value in the returned tuple (the filename).
`("_4_201703150220", "201703150220")[0]` becomes `"_4_201703150220"`

Comment: This works only for a case. I have recently edited the question please refer.Thanks though

Comment: That is rather different from your initial question - are you trying to keep only the latest directory for each day?

Comment: not for each day but  U can consider. Those digits between underscore is an id